# Javascript Picture Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the basic code shown on https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp to create an automatic slideshow for a website. Everything seems to be the same and for some reason, the slideshow is not working. 
HTML:

```
    <article id="elements">
            <h2 class="major">Pictures</h2>



            <div class="slideshow">


                <script src="assets/slideshow.js"></script>

                <img id="slide" src="images/colin1.jpg" style="width:75%">
                <img id="slide" src="images/luke.jpg" style="width:75%">
                <img id="slide" src="images/shep.jpg" style="width:75%">
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body #elements .slideshow #slide {
display: none;
    }
```

JS:

```
    var index = 0;
    slideshow();

    function slideshow() {
var i, x;

x = document.getElementById("slide");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
}

index++;

if (index > x.length) {
    index = 1;
}

x[index-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(slideshow, 2000);

    }
```

I appreciate anyone's help, and any ideas!

Comment: Have you confirmed that `src="assets/slideshow.js"` is actually where you have `slideshow.js`?

Comment: Note that the demo uses `class` and you are using `id` to identify each slide. You should never have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: @Sablefoste I just checked again, and it is the correct directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` only returns one item, not an array, so you cannot use it to get all slides, use `getElementsByClassName` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), and change id for classes:

```js
var index = 0;
slideshow();

function slideshow() {
  var i, x;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  index++;
  if (index > x.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(slideshow, 2000);
  console.log('changed image')

}
```

```css
#elements .slideshow #slide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article id="elements">
  <h2 class="major">Pictures</h2>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <script src="assets/slideshow.js"></script>
    <img class="slide" src="images/colin1.jpg" style="width:75%">
    <img class="slide" src="images/luke.jpg" style="width:75%">
    <img class="slide" src="images/shep.jpg" style="width:75%">
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Gordon.

When selecting by ID only one element will be selected.

If you switch to using classes. e.g.
`<img class="slide" src="images/colin1.jpg" style="width:75%">`

Then you can select all the images using.
`x = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");`

which will return a `nodeList`, a similar construction to an Array but with different methods; that can be accessed via index. `x[0]`, `x[1]`, `x[2]`.

hope this helps.